# Can an index speed up a query with GROUP BY/aggregate over the whole table (no selectivity)?

Tags: index, performance, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

Let's say i have a table with 3 columns a,b and c.

Could i possible speed up a query that looks like this by using index(es) ??

```
SELECT a,b,SUM(c)  # or AVG(c)
FROM table
GROUP BY a,b
ORDER BY a,b
;
```

If the above question is positive, **what type of index** do you recommend and **how would this work?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not likely. `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` typically entail a sort. However, in this case a `HashAggregate` is used (likely because we're working with the whole table).

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT x % 5 AS a, x % 10 AS b, x AS c
FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x;
```

With the HashAggregate plan,

```
# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a,b,sum(c) FROM foo GROUP BY a,b ORDER BY a,b;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=23668.04..23668.16 rows=50 width=14) (actual time=611.607..611.608 rows=10 loops=1)
   Sort Key: a, b
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=23666.00..23666.62 rows=50 width=14) (actual time=611.589..611.593 rows=10 loops=1)
         Group Key: a, b
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16166.00 rows=1000000 width=14) (actual time=0.012..71.157 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.168 ms
 Execution time: 611.665 ms
```

so we add an index...

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON foo (a,b);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE foo;
```

... still shows the same query plan. So we disable HashAggregate

```
SET enable_hashagg = false;
```

And, try again..

```
# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a,b,sum(c) FROM foo GROUP BY a,b ORDER BY a,b;
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..61292.04 rows=50 width=14) (actual time=108.149..655.536 rows=10 loops=1)
   Group Key: a, b
   ->  Index Scan using idx on foo  (cost=0.42..53791.41 rows=1000000 width=14) (actual time=0.066..272.299 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.121 ms
 Execution time: 655.594 ms
(5 rows)
```

And, it takes more time 655ms compared to the previous 611ms.

## Need faster?

If that's not fast enough (and 611ms to group and sum a million rows isn't bad). Then you can use a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) if your workload permits it (if the query is hot and/or infrequently updated),

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW foo2 AS
SELECT a,b,sum(c)
FROM foo
GROUP BY a,b
ORDER BY a,b;
```

Now you're down to sub-MS time when `TABLE foo2`. Then just do `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW foo2;` to refresh the view. Or, you can create a trigger update another table and update it with triggers.

## On the actually column being aggregated.

There are some exceptions, but `sum()` isn't one of them. Most aggregates do not use an index because they usually do not have a need for one. The exceptions are the aggregates that are order-specific (like `min()` and `max()`). So for instance, if after we created the index on `(a,b)` you run a `sum(a)`,

```
# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT sum(a) FROM foo;
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=18666.00..18666.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=287.063..287.063 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16166.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.015..85.435 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.098 ms
 Execution time: 287.104 ms
(4 rows)
```

you can see that it still uses a seq scan.. You'll see the same plan for `sum(c)` which doesn't have an index at all. Now here is the kicker,

```
# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT min(a) FROM foo;
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.48..0.49 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.48 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.036..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Index Only Scan using idx on foo  (cost=0.42..56291.41 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (a IS NOT NULL)
                 Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning time: 0.171 ms
 Execution time: 0.080 ms
(8 rows)
```

`min(a)` unlike `sum(a)` can make use of an ordering, and so the query planner realizes that the index scan, which isn't free, has a benefit.

### Proof using index on (a,b,c)

For whatever reason if you want to see proof that a further index on `c` doesn't matter for the purposes of summing (ask a question if after reading the above you still do not understand why),

```
-- turn this back on we turned it off earlier
SET enable_hashagg = true;
DROP INDEX idx;
CREATE INDEX idx ON foo (a,b,c);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE foo;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a,b,sum(c) FROM foo GROUP BY a,b ORDER BY a,b;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=23668.04..23668.16 rows=50 width=14) (actual time=608.888..608.889 rows=10 loops=1)
   Sort Key: a, b
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=23666.00..23666.62 rows=50 width=14) (actual time=608.869..608.871 rows=10 loops=1)
         Group Key: a, b
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16166.00 rows=1000000 width=14) (actual time=0.015..72.613 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.130 ms
 Execution time: 608.947 ms
(8 rows)
```

No improvement whatsoever. Disabling `hashagg` still shows no improvement whatsoever.

## TLDR;

In this specific and simple use case indexes don't matter. The planner chooses the best method.

Comment: Okay but what about aggregate functions, do they speed up too by using some index or it's all about group by and order by ?

Comment: Can't speed up aggregation. That has to visit every row regardless.

Comment: So i guess in these kind of queries, my main concern is to speed up any kind of sorting required by group or order clauses then.

Comment: Well, you _could_ speed up aggregation too by providing a covering index and thus ensuring index-only access.

Comment: @mustaccio nope, I don't think so but TIAS. I was totally wrong on this one. I created some test data and tried it. I updated the question. HashAggregate is just too fast to beat. The index lookup is just too slow if you need to use every row.

Comment: Could i use an index on (a,b,c) ?

Comment: @Kon updated with that.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't see a test with an `(a,b,c)` index. I think it is worth adding that.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ updated.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I think i have a better view of what's going on now..Could you please explain how the index can help on group by sorting?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thnx. can you add the plan, without the HashAggregate?

Comment: That's another whole question, imho. But it's simple. If I take the White Pages (assuming you're old enough to know what that is), and I removed them from the binding and mixed them all up, will you find Grandma's phone number in more time or less time than if I gave you an pristine copy of the White Pages. That's a pretty good analogy. Your data is an unbound and scrambled copy of the White Pages. And, the index is the method by which you know how to scan through it. It's sorted alphabetically by the last name, and that makes grouping by first two characters of the last name easy.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Very nice explanation!!

So, my real problem from start was to speed up a AVG/GROUP BY query in a very large table(about 9 mil rows) using index(es). What i get from your answer as a conclusion, is that i **can't** because this type of the type of the aggregate function i use. Note that the query retrieves 1000 rows only.

Comment: Yes, but *retrieves* is not the right word there for this context though. You're being presented with a 1000 row summary, but the database is retrieving *every row*  in order to calculate the `sum()`. Normally, with an index, it's actually retrieving *fewer* rows than would otherwise be retrieved or it can make use of a specific ordering. None of those apply here. So every one of your 9 million rows must be visited to calculate the sum. As an aside, the same is true with `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl` you [can't make that faster with an index.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting)